# Converting tensorflow models to cntk model format to perform inference task

Tags: c#, tensorflow, model, cntk

I have several models that I would like to use in the new CNTK Library C# API. However, I cannot find how to convert a saved tensorflow models (files such as .ckpt and/or .pb with .pbtxt) to cntk model format (.model).
My goal is perform the inference task of the tensorflow's object detection api in c# using cntk. I can run inference in python for tensorflow but I would like to do the same in c#.
Any suggestion will be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

There is no TF to CNTK converter that I'm aware of. If you just want to do eval, try TensorFlowSharp: https://github.com/migueldeicaza/TensorFlowSharp/tree/master/TensorFlowSharp

Or you can always train your model with CNTK, in Python or C# or R.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @ChaZ. In fact, I am using TensorFlowSharp already but I was thinking to give a try to the new Microsoft tool. Actually CNTK devs told me a few weeks ago that they are working on it and maybe soon it will be a converter. Till now, tensorflowSharp can do the job perfectly.

Comment: That is true. We are working on TF to CNTK model converter. I don't have an ETA yet, so I didn't mention that. :)

Comment: Thank you for your message. One of your coworkers wrote here before but he deleted his message and that is the reason this question had no answer when you see it. Please, write me back here when the tool is ready. I am a C# programmer and it will be better for me work with CNTK since I am more familiar to C# than python. :)